# Apps Script openById

Tags: google-apps-script

The `openByID(Id)` method of the `SpreadsheetApp` is described here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)

the reference states:

`Note that the spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side.
 // It is opened on the server only (for modification by the script).`

is it recommended (the reference does not mention) that  I:

a) should definitely 
b) would follow best practice if I were to 
 
or c) need not

. . . close the spreadsheet when I am done?  Do the servers just take care of that?

Many thanks, Malcolm

Comment: Thank you for the edit, Aftab H.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to "close" the opened spreadsheet. There is also no `SpreadsheetApp.closeById()` method. The Apps Script servers will properly close resources when the variables go out of scope.

Comment: Thank you tehhowch, that was my hope and assumption.  I was just wary that I was opening many spreadsheets and not explicitly closing them down, I didn't want to be the unwitting actor of Google's demise :-)

Comment: You'd hit the existing [Apps Script API quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) well before you could take down Google :)